# How to create a tinder/bumble like "Edit Profile Images" page in android studio with firebase?

Tags: java, android, html, firebase

I'm trying to create an app where you can add profile images from your mobile device, then save it to firebase, and retrieve it from firebase as well, as efficiently as possible.

A few questions:

1: How do these big dating apps such as bumble/tinder create the edit profile image UI where you upload your profile images and rearrange them? Do they place cardviews into a gridview, seeing as how these cards have the ability to be dragged to rearrange the position? Also they normally have a small x button attached to delete the image, so it would be a cardview, right?

I'm currently using ImageViews for testing and wanted to incorporate the ability to add more, but my code is horrible and it overwrites the images in the firebase DB if I return to the page and add a new image.

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        />

</LinearLayout>



public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mBack;
    private ImageView mImage1, mImage2, mImage3;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDb, mTagsDb;
    private String userId, phone, image1Url, image2Url, image3Url, userSex;
    private Uri resultUri1, resultUri2, resultUri3;
    private ArrayList<Uri> resultUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    private ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewsList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    final int MaxTags = 5;
    final int MaxImages = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mImage1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);
        mImage2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);
        mImage3 = findViewById(R.id.image3);
        mBack = findViewById(R.id.back);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
        getUserInfo();

        mImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        mImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
        });
        mImage3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
            }
        });

        mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveUserInformation();
                finish();

            }
        });

private void saveUserInformation() {
        phone = mPhoneField.getText().toString();

        Map userInfo = new HashMap();
        userInfo.put("phone", phone);
        mUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);
        if(resultUri != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < resultUri.size(); i++)
            {   String num = String.valueOf(i);
                final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child(num);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri.get(i));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(data);
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                final int finalI = i+1;
                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                newImage.put("image"+ finalI +"Url", uri.toString());
                                mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);

                                finish();
                                return;
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                finish();
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }



        }else{
            finish();
        }
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> values;
    private void getUserInfo() {

        mUserDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){


                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if(map.get("phone") != null){
                        phone = map.get("phone").toString();
                        mPhoneField.setText(phone);
                    }
                    if(map.get("sex") != null){
                        userSex = map.get("sex").toString();
                    }

                    Glide.clear(mImage1);
                    Glide.clear(mImage2);
                    Glide.clear(mImage3);
                    if(MaxImages == 3) {
                        imageViewsList.add(mImage1);
                        imageViewsList.add(mImage2);
                        imageViewsList.add(mImage3);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < MaxImages; i ++)
                    {
                        int b = i+1;
                        if(map.get("image"+b+"Url") != null){
                            String url = map.get("image"+b+"Url").toString();
                            switch(url){
                                case "default":
                                    imageViewsList.get(i).setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                                    //Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mImage1);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(url).into(imageViewsList.get(i));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            resultUri1 = imageUri;
            mImage1.setImageURI(resultUri1);
            resultUri.add(resultUri1);
        }
        if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            resultUri2 = imageUri;
            mImage2.setImageURI(resultUri2);
            resultUri.add(resultUri2);
        }
        if(requestCode == 3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            resultUri3 = imageUri;
            mImage3.setImageURI(resultUri3);
            resultUri.add(resultUri3);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I can upload images to the imageviews fine and save them to firebase, but for example if I upload 2 images, then save and return to upload a 3rd image, that image overwrites image 1. Does anyone have a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

So after looking at the other apps at my disposal again, I've realized that it seems they upload the image to firebase after the onResultActivity of the image selection of your phone gallery. So i've simplified my code to do the same and it works much better. Code now works but I just need to resize the images to fit the imageviews properly, other than that no complaints.

If you have a better and more efficient way of writing this code, please comment, efficiency is key and I would appreciate your input.

```
 protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mImage1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);
        mImage2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);
        mImage3 = findViewById(R.id.image3);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

        getUserInfo();
        getUserTags();

            mImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
            mImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                }
            });
            mImage3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
                }
            });

    private void getUserInfo() {

            mUserDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){

                        Glide.clear(mImage1);
                        if(map.get("image1Url") != null){
                            image1Url = map.get("image1Url").toString();
                            switch(image1Url){
                                case "default":
                                    mImage1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                                    //Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mImage1);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(image1Url).into(mImage1);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(map.get("image2Url") != null){
                            image2Url = map.get("image2Url").toString();
                            switch(image2Url){
                                case "default":
                                    mImage2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                                    //Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mImage1);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(image2Url).into(mImage2);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(map.get("image3Url") != null){
                            image3Url = map.get("image3Url").toString();
                            switch(image3Url){
                                case "default":
                                    mImage3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                                    //Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mImage1);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(image3Url).into(mImage3);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final Uri resultUri = imageUri;
                if(resultUri != null){
                    final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child("image1");
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] databytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(databytes);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("image1Url", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);
                                    mImage1.setImageURI(resultUri);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    finish();
                }

            }
            if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final Uri resultUri = imageUri;
                if(resultUri != null){
                    final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child("image2");
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] databytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(databytes);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("image2Url", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);
                                    mImage2.setImageURI(resultUri);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    finish();
                }
            }
            if(requestCode == 3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final Uri resultUri = imageUri;
                if(resultUri != null){
                    final StorageReference filePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId).child("image3");
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
                    byte[] databytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(databytes);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Map newImage = new HashMap();
                                    newImage.put("image3Url", uri.toString());
                                    mUserDb.updateChildren(newImage);
                                    mImage3.setImageURI(resultUri);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Upload Failed! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
```